How to check if browser support stream HEVC by Javascript
My app use Javascript and shaka player to play video stream (live and VOD). We intent to use HEVC stream (h.265), but as I see this is new so not much browser support.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs#hevc_h.265
Is there is way to check if browser support HEVC. If yes, we will run HEVC stream otherwise we will use H.264.
Thank you.

In safari you can use video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'), though I tend to use hls.js and their built-in window.Hls.isSupported()

thank you for useful information. my app use shaka player. but i will try

Shaka has methods called probeSupport and isBrowserSupported...

probeSupport give multi result, can you let me know which field indicate that browser support HEVC or not:   video/mp4; codecs="hev1.1.6.L93.90"
video/mp4; codecs="hev1.2.4.L153.B0"; eotf="smpte2084"
video/mp4; codecs="hvc1.1.6.L93.90"
video/mp4; codecs="hvc1.2.4.L153.B0"; eotf="smpte2084"

I mean, going from the answer below it would be hev1.1.6.L93.B0, just like video.canPlayType

With canPlayType, you can check if the video element can play a type of HEVC codec, it will return one of these values "probably", "maybe", or "" ( empty string ) in case it couldn't play this type.
function checkHEVCSupport() {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    var isHEVCSupported = video.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="hev1.1.6.L93.B0"') || video.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="hvc1.1.6.L93.B0"');

    return isHEVCSupported;
}

const doesGEVCSupported = checkHEVCSupport()

if (doesGEVCSupported ) {
    // here you could check if the value is "maybe" or "probably"
    console.log('HEVC could be supported');
} else {
    console.log('HEVC is not supported, using H.264 instead');
}

Codec guide

Thank you. I see you use 'video/mp4; codecs="hev1.1.6.L93.B0"', is this should be hard code?

@vanminhquangtri, not need to be hardcoded, but these are parameters, for example hev1 stores these parameters in the video stream itself, while hvc1 stores them in the file container, then you need to specify the profile, level, tier, like video/mp4; codecs="hev1.${profile}.${level}.${tier}"

@vanminhquangtri, but for case, just to check if the browser supports HEVC stream or not, you can just hardcoded it.
